# How to use Hashicorp Vault with React?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React app with .env files set up to hold my env configurations. I don't commit my .env files to git for security reasons. I need to use the Hashicorp vault to work in CI/CD Concourse pipelines.

```
API_END_POINT=https://test.com // sample
```

Comment: which CICD pipeline you're using , if jenkins add a env variable in build job

Comment: @Hitheshk, I am using Concourse

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass environment variables to a task using the params attribute in your pipeline YAML file.

check these docs
https://concourse-ci.org/config-basics.html#schema.env-vars
either you use vars https://concourse-ci.org/vars.html

```
jobs:
- name: my-job
  plan:
  - task: my-task
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source:
          repository: busybox
      params:
        API_END_POINT: value
      run:
        path: sh
        args:
        - -c
        - |
          echo "$API_END_POINT"
    ...
```